# How to start sbt console and automatically evaluate some expressions?

Tags: scala, sbt

When using `sbt console` I find myself repeatedly entering some import statements.  It would be great if there was a way to tell sbt to always run commands.  Is there a way?

At the moment I have a kinda crufty solution:

```
( echo "import my.app._
import my.app.is.sooo.cool._" && cat ) | sbt console
```

Googleability words:

Initial commands, first commands, initial expressions, build file, initial statements, startup expressions, startup commands, startup statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [initialCommands](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Scala.html#Define+the+initial+commands+evaluated+when+entering+the+Scala+REPL):

```
initialCommands in console := """import my.app._
import my.app.is.sooo.cool._"""
```

Answer (score -2):

Given that "sbt console" lets you run the scala repl, why not just create a custom .scala file (say "default.scala") where to store all the imports, and then just run `:load /path/to/default.scala`? This would achieve what you need in a persistent way.

Comment: When I run that in the console I get `<console>:2: error: illegal start of definition`

Comment: Have you run "sbt console", and then from it's prompt ```:load /path/to/default.scala```?

Comment: No I have `initialCommands in console := ":load /path/to/default.scala"`. I want to use the `build.sbt` to specify this, rather than it being a hoop to jump through upon every `sbt console` start.